# Remove .html from url allways failed

Tags: html, apache, mod-rewrite

I try to remove `.html` extension in my url but still not work.

this my .httaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$  /$1 [L,R=301]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that with `RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]` your rule just rewrites `index.php` and not all `*.html`

If you just want to remove the `.html` on the end of your url you just need this in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.html [L]
```

[Official Apache Documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html)

But note that this won't redirect users from `https://example.com/page.html` to `https://example.com/page`

For example: you have to replace all your anchor tags href value from `<a href="https://example.com/page.html">Link</a>` to `<a href="https://example.com/page">Link</a>`

If you want to learn more about the `.htaccess` and what you can do with it, i recommend you [this](https://tecadmin.net/remove-file-extension-from-url-using-htaccess/) article.

Comment: I only want it for the article. When I added the above code, it resulted in a 404 error.

Comment: Are you sure that your `.htaccess` is used? So does you https redirection for example work?

Comment: I have added the code to the .htaccess file but it didn't work.

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.html [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: try to remove the rest of your content in the htaccess file (and once again, are you sure that your apache server is using your htaccess?) so be sure that your file is named .htaccess and not .htaccess.txt or something like that